# Format of 16 GB USB drive seems stuck

Tags: usb, hard-drive, format

I started formatting a thumb drive about an hour ago. I initiated the process through the file system, but now the drive doesn't show up there. So I opened the disk utility. It is on the list there, but there is a spinning icon that it's busy.

It's been a long time now. Is this how this should be working? It doesn't seem right. What needs to happen for the formatting to complete?

Comment: Formatting takes seconds normally. How did you "initiated the process through the file system"?

Comment: @Pilot6 I right-clicked on it and chose 'format' from the popup menu.

Comment: Well, that's not the best way. I would prefer using `gparted`. Some process is frozen.

Comment: How can I proceed? Is there a safe way to stop the process?

Comment: There is a good chance that it is successful already. You never mentioned the system you are using. If Ubuntu 18.04, the new Gnome desktop has lots of bugs like this. It's unusable for me. You can try to pull it out, reinsert and see what happens. You can always format it again.

Comment: Ok. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with a Budgie desktop, which i guess is a GNOME variant.

Comment: Alright, it had indeed completed successfully. It showed up properly once I removed it and reinserted it. Thanks.

Comment: That was a GUI bug not to show it finished.

Comment: Please share details of the environment you are using. The type of format you are applying(zero format or normal). There may be the following reasons:- 1:- There might be Problem with the port you are connecting with. 2:- The Pen drive is damaged.